# Shifting in MIPS using a formula

Tags: assembly, mips, sll

Im learning MIPS and coming from a procedural programming background its proving difficult. This is a question i came across when it came to shifting. If there are any pointers in answering it, it would be appreciated.

Suppose that rt is a register that contains an integer. Explain why
the instruction

```
sll $rd, $rt, h
```

has the effective of putting

```
2^h ∗ rt
```

in register rd

Comment: Go learn about binary or just elementary maths. In any base shifting by a digit means multiplying by the base. E.g. in decimal appending zeroes is multiplying by 10. Similarly in binary, it's multiplying by 2. Repeated multiplication is thus scaling by powers of the base.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have anything to do with prodecural programming but rather binary numbers.

Some examples using 8 bit numbers:

If you have the number `1` (decimal) - in binary that would be `0000 0001`

If you shift left by 1, you move all the numbers up by 1, and insert a 0 into the new shift space

So now you would have binary `0000 0010` - or `2` decimal.

Shift left another gives `0000 0100` or `4` decimal.

So if you shift the original number 1 left by 2, you have 4.

Or looking at it as a pattern:

1 left shift = *2  (2^1)

2 left shift = *4 (2^2)

All of which looks like

```
2^h ∗ rt
```